# Find a sequence of probability measures $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which converges in the weak* topology

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to find a sequence of probability measures $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which converges in the weak* topology to $\mu$, on a measurable metric space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and a closed set $F\in \mathcal{F}$ for which $\lim \sup \mu_n(F)<\mu(F)$. Can someone help me?

Comment: A good candidate for $\mu$ would be a point mass.